# High battery impact on iOS from Display and Overhead

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, performance, mobile

I ran the iOS/Swift app I'm working on through the Xcode profiler and found that the app's energy usage is very high. Xcode isn't reporting a high CPU usage, memory usage, or disk usage - just a high battery usage. When I click on the details of the Energy Impact tab in Xcode, it shows high energy usage from Overhead, Display, and Location. I understand why Location has an energy impact (the 20% impact from that is understandable, since location services is on at all times when running the app in order to maximize location accuracy), but I don't understand why Display and Overhead have such a large impact on the app's battery life. I would love to implement a fix to improve this, but I don't even understand what parts of the app affect Display usage and there seems to be very little information out there on the topic. Even Apple's own documentation on reducing energy usage isn't very helpful. If anybody has any additional information on how to find out why the battery usage of the app is so high, it would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a screenshot of the energy usage details recorded in Xcode, in case they are helpful.
[iOS app energy usage statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8e9c.png)